# JQuery get contents of closest ancestor's descendant with selector

Tags: jquery

I have spent the last hour on JQuery, Stackoverflow and Google trying to find out what the hell I'm doing wrong!

I am trying to limit the number in the input so that it must be between 1 and a maximum number, which is defined in span.maximum

The HTML:

```
<li>
  <div>
    <span class="maximum">5</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="number" onchange="limiter(this);">
  </div>
</li>
```

The Jquery:

```
function limiter(input) {
max = $(this).closest("li").find(".maximum").text();

if (input.value < 1) input.value = 1, alert(max);
if (input.value > max) input.value = max, alert(max);
}
```

It works if replace line 2 with

```
max = $(".maximum").text();
```

But I'm trying to go up to the nearest li ancestor and then down to that li's span.maximum. There may be other DOM elements so it can't just be a set number of parents up, then a set number of children down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method `this` refers to the window object, you need to use then `input` reference to find the closest element because `input` refers to the changed element. Also you might want to convert the values to number before comparison

```js
function limiter(input) {
  var max = +$(input).closest("li").find(".maximum").text() || 0;
  var value = +input.value;

  if (value < 1) {
    input.value = 1;
    alert(max);
  }
  if (value > max) {
    input.value = max;
    alert(max);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <span class="maximum">5</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="number" onchange="limiter(this);" />
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

It will more jQuery-ish to use jQuery event handlers

```js
$('.myinput').change(function() {
  var max = +$(this).closest("li").find(".maximum").text() || 0;
  var value = +$(this).val() || 0;

  if (value < 1) {
    $(this).val(1);
  } else if (value > max) {
    $(this).val(max);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <span class="maximum">5</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="myinput" type="number" />
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works. Goddamn it! Thanks Arun, you legendary Jquery badass.

Answer (score 0):

I hate event assignment in HTML as I am never sure what 'this' is pointing to :), so I would recommend assigning event in code, like this:

```
function limiter() {
    max = $(this).closest("li").find(".maximum").text();
if (this.value < 1) this.value = 1, alert(max);
if (this.value > max) this.value = max, alert(max);
}

$('input').on('change', limiter);
```